# Some warnings are reported on the proxy class generated by the svcutil

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

During the implementation of a duplex service, I created a new class and I decorated it with the attribute `DataContract`: moreover, I decorated the properties of this class with the attribute `DataMember`, including the property `public IPEndPoint Endpoint { get; set; }`.

Then I launched svcutil which has generated the `generatedProxy.cs` and the `app.config` files. The build of the project is successful, but some warnings are reported as follows:

> The type 'System.Net.IPEndPoint' in
>   'C:\Users\vincenzo\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\SampleDuplex\Client\generatedProxy.cs' conflicts with
>   the imported type 'System.Net.IPEndPoint' in 'c:\Program
>   Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll'.
>   Using the type defined in 'C:\Users\vincenzo\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\SampleDuplex\Client\generatedProxy.cs'. C:\Users\vincenzo\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\SampleDuplex\Client\generatedProxy.cs   90  28  Client

What causes these warnings?

Comment: Last time I did this, the code generated by `svcutil` triggerred a small legion of warnings. I hate to admit it, but I was forced not to care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that the generated file contained the definition of the namespace `System.Net`, and within this namespace there was also the definition of the `IPEndPoint` class: this was in conflict with the definition of the .NET Framework. In order to resolve the problem, I added the `/reference` option to svcutil command, as follows:

1. I moved into the path `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0`
2. I added the option `/reference:System.dll`

As a result, the definition of the namespace System.Net is no longer present in the generated file and after the build no warnings are reported.